# Protractor: Call a method within onprepare function

Tags: javascript, protractor

I am trying to call a custom function in the onPrepare method in my local protractor config  which extends a global protrator config but am not able to get it to work. Inorder to make it a bit more simpler I wrote it like this inside my protractor.config

```
module.exports = {
    foo: function() {
        console.log('testing');

    },
    // A callback function called once protractor is ready and available, and
    // before the specs are executed
    // You can specify a file containing code to run by setting onPrepare to
    // the filename string.
    onPrepare: function() {
        //  At this point, global 'protractor' object will be set up, and jasmine
        //  will be available. For example, you can add a Jasmine reporter with:
        //      jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmine.JUnitXmlReporter(
        //          'outputdir/', true, true));




        console.log(foo);


    },
};
```

My local.protractor.config is

```
var globalConf = require('./protractor.conf.js');
exports.config = globalConf;
```

But I get the error as foo being undefined.

```
[launcher] Error: ReferenceError: foo is not defined
```

Is there a way to add a custom method that onprepare can call which I can call from in my local.protractor.config

Answer (score 1):

Try this (move your function away from exporting object):

```
var foo = function () {
    console.log('BAR')
}

exports.config = {
    //other params here
    onPrepare: function() {
        foo()
    },
    //other params here
};
```

Comment: While that works I needed it to be inside export.config so that I can override it somehow in my local.protractor.config. Will update the question since it seems I need to now